Zero inflation: OLS vs Poisson
I am working with a dataset with many zeros in the outcome variables (ranging from 50% to 95% zeros). I am using the glmmTMB package to run zero-inflated Poisson models. Half the time, these fail to converge and produce a lot of NAs with the estimates. I've noticed that running the Poisson models without the zero-inflated component yields way less error messages.
I know that the zero-inflated estimations are out due to these convergence difficulties. I will need to conceptually justify the use of standard Poisson over OLS. Is Poisson better suited to handle lots of zeros than OLS? Is there any relevant literature you could point me toward to?
Best

Standard Poisson actually might be OK. But it depends. For example, for a Poisson with mean = 0.1, I would expect that ~ 90% of the responses would be zeroes. This is not zero-inflated, it is a regular old Poisson.

I think to answer your question, people will need more info. What's the study and what outcome do you want to achieve? What's the response variables and model structure. etc.

No. When the correct method gives convergence difficulties, you do not go to an incorrect method. It would take a lot more info to identify why the models don't converge, but, if you cannot solve the convergence problems, you may have to say that the data you have don't let you do what you want.

@PeterFlom I think what is screwing with the convergence is that I am running a model with 2500 fixed effects units and 12000 observations. There are 4 to 5 observations per fixed effect. Running the model with random effects or with fixed effects at a more aggregate level (instead of counties, I run states) does not lead to convergence issues.

That sounds like you have identified the problem. County level data has other problems, too.

If you have count data, and especially count data with a low mean, then a model designed for count data (such as Poisson or negative binomial) is probably the right thing to do.
Note that "lots of zeros" is not the same as "zero-inflated", e.g. see Warton (2005).
If you fit a zero-inflated model to data that are not zero-inflated, you may get warnings because the zero-inflation will approach zero; this effect is estimated on the logit (log-odds) scale, so the parameter will approach -Inf.
In the example below glmmTMB produces a very small estimate of the zero-inflation (logit = -15.98 → prob = 1.15e-7), but not any warnings. But you could easily get warnings from a more complex model.
In general an estimate of the zero-inflation approaching zero would be a perfectly justifiable reason not to include the zero-inflation component ...
set.seed(102)
dd <- data.frame(x = rpois(10000, lambda = 0.1))
library(glmmTMB)
glmmTMB(x ~ 1, family = poisson, ziformula = ~1, data  = dd)


Warton, David I. “Many Zeros Does Not Mean Zero Inflation: Comparing the Goodness-of-Fit of Parametric Models to Multivariate Abundance Data.” Environmetrics 16, no. 3 (2005): 275–89. https://doi.org/10.1002/env.702.
